# Propositional Logic - Truth tables - with formulas and given truth values

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Qu
Morgan Kaufmann.
http://myweb.sabanciuniv.edu/rdehkharghani/files/2016/02/The-Morgan-Kaufmann-Series-in-Data-Management-Systems-Jiawei-Han-Micheline-Kamber-Jian-Pei-Data-Mining.-Concepts-and-Techniques-3rd-Edition-Morgan-Kaufmann-2011.pdf
Morgan Kaufmann.
http://myweb.sabanciuniv.edu/rdehkharghani/files/2016/02/The-Morgan-Kaufmann-Series-in-Data-Management-Systems-Jiawei-Han-Micheline-Kamber-Jian-Pei-Data-Mining.-Concepts-and-Techniques-3rd-Edition-Morgan-Kaufmann-2011.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> a.v) $(¬((¬(¬ R)) \vee Q)) \wedge (¬ R)$ I am struggling on this last question, I am getting confused on how to contruct the truth table.

Just substitute the truth values then evaluate the connectives one at a time

$\begin{array}{c:c:c:c:c:c:c:c:c|ll}(\lnot & (\lnot & \lnot & R) & \vee & Q)) & \wedge &\lnot & R&(¬((¬(¬ R)) \vee Q)) \wedge (¬ R)
\\ &&&\color{blue}T&&\color{blue}F&&&\color{blue}T &(¬((¬(¬ T)) \vee F)) \wedge (¬ T)
\\ &&\color{blue}F&\color{silver}T&&\color{blue}F&&\color{blue}F&\color{silver}T&(¬((¬(F)) \vee F)) \wedge (F) & \tiny\textsf{Hmm...something and false...}
\\ &\color{blue}T&\color{silver}F&\color{silver}T&&\color{blue}F&&\color{blue}F&\color{silver}T&(¬((T) \vee F)) \wedge (F)
\\ &\color{silver}T&\color{silver}F&\color{silver}T&\color{blue}T&\color{silver}F&&\color{blue}F&\color{silver}T&(¬(T)) \wedge (F)
\\ \color{blue}F&\color{silver}T&\color{silver}F&\color{silver}T&\color{silver}T&\color{silver}F&&\color{blue}F&\color{silver}T&(F) \wedge (F)
\\ \color{silver}F&\color{silver}T&\color{silver}F&\color{silver}T&\color{silver}T&\color{silver}F&\color{blue}F&\color{silver}F&\color{silver}T&(F)
\end{array}$

> a.i) $P → Q \land R$ .... I got (False)

$T~\to~T\land F$ is false $\checkmark$

> a.ii) P → R / Q .... I got (True)

$T~\to~T\lor F$ is true $\checkmark$

> a.iii) (P → Q) → R .... I got (False)

$(T\to F)\to T$ is true. (*ex falso (sequitur) quodlibet*)

> a.iv) ((¬ P) → Q) → (¬ R) .... I got (False)

$((\neg T)\to F)\to(\lnot T)$ is false $\checkmark$

Comment: Off-topic: Upvote for the $\LaTeX-\text{truth table}$!! Can I ask if you did it manually? I'm amazed ^-^

Comment: It's fairly easy to set up manually with the online preview.  @manooooh

Comment: that's true. Thank you for answering, today I can go to sleep in peace...

Comment: Thank you for your reply Graham! Why is a.iii) true I have F-> T ? and for the first question.. is it true? thank you so much

Comment: $T\to F$ is $F$, so $(T\to F)\to T$ is $F\to T$, which is $T$. @nh50  Re: the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).